# Create Dynamic Excel Macro for printing to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, office-2013

I have an excel document with a couple hundred lines in it. Basically the document contains a list of users with information for each user.  Each user can have multiple different rows of information.

I have been trying for the past couple hours to create a macro that allows for an excel file to sort users according to their name, then take like names and print them to a pdf document with that users name and date printed as the file name.

> 

`Example:`

  1 User1   data   data   data
  2 User1   data   data   data
  3 User1   data   data   data

  4 User2   data   data   data
  5 User2   data   data   data

  6 User3   data   data   data
  7 User3   data   data   data
  8 User3   data   data   data
  9 User3   data   data   data

> 

So basically the column with the name "User1" needs to be printed with all that rows information into its own PDF document. Same goes for "User2" and "User3" and such forth.

I tried using the "Record Macro" option with excel but that more gave me ideas rather than a working solution. This is my record macro though its not much good for what I am wanting to do. If someone could provide some guidance or provide some help I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

`Sub ExportnamestoPDF2()
'
' ExportnamestoPDF2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j
'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-36
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("document - Copy").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("document - Copy").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("document - Copy").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Rows("2:4").Select
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use autofilter.

I would sort by user name, then create a loop "A" that prints, and a loop "B" within that which goes row-by-row and evaluates the user name for changes.

Something like:

```
i = 2
lastRow  = 0
Do
  firstRow = i
  Do
    If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
      lastRow = i
    End
    i = i + 1
  While lastRow < i
  Rows(firstRow & ":" & lastRow).PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
```

This assumes that your user ID is in column 1 ("A").

But this just prints, I guess?  I don't see where your macro is saving a file anywhere.